# matrix-inverse in a quadratic form

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let $A:=\{a_{ij}\}$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric, and positive definite matrix. It's well known that, for some $n$-vector $x$, $x'Ax$ is a scalar:
$$
x'Ax=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_i x_j.
$$ 
**What can be said about the quadratic form $x'A^{-1}x$?**

**Is it possible to write is as a function of the $a_{ij}$?**

Comment: One can find a very dirty form using adjugate matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: As you said, it becomes quite complicate. My particular interest is to assess what happens to the elements of the $A^{-1}$ as a few elements of $A$ tend to infinity. More specifically, let $a_{1j}\to\infty$ and $a_{i1}\to\infty$, that is, all the elements of the first column and first row tend to infinity. What can be said about the elements of $A^{-1}$?